# CSOM work with column with space in the name?

Tags: csom

I'm trying to do an application which writes in another sharepoint list
Today, I have a new trouble, if my column contains some spaces, my program returns me : Column does not exist
So here an example: I have a column name: My setting values, if I want to write in this, I use this piece of code:

```
                   oListItem[variable.FieldNameTarget] = variable.FieldValue;
                   oListItem.Update();
```

So I know that SharePoint replace space by *x0200*, so before to reach this piece of code, I use:

```
  foreach(var item in m_objProjectList)
            {
               item.FieldNameTarget=item.FieldNameTarget.Replace(@" ", "_x0020_");
            }
```

But now, I have an error message:column "My_x0200_setting_x0200values" doesn't exist, so is there another way to achieve that?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that first find the internal name of the column and then use that.

You can find the internal name of any Felds using C# code as well.

This is shown [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/75ca6fab-56f3-4bf4-aae0-2d29821778a2/how-to-get-internal-names-of-columns-in-sharepoint-lists?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I think it's because my name is too long:
I use the name: Synchronise with your new sharepoint list, but when I check in my internal name, I just have: Synchronise%5Fx0020%5Fwith%5Fx0020%5Fyour%5Fx0020%5Fne
So my problem could come frome here?

***Edit**** After a quick search: SharePoint name for a list is limited to 32 characters

Comment: That a good finding. here are some reference for future readers. http://benhuang.blogspot.com/2009/08/32-character-limit-in-sharepoint-lists.html and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/113007